# Redux state and useState not sync

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to set my reduxState to useState, but the problem is reduxState come after rendering then useState still have null which was got at the first rendering.
Expect: reduxState pass every change or update to useState.

```
    const Account: React.FC<Props> = ({ logInAction, userDataStore }) => {
        const [userValues, setUserValues] = useState<User>(userDataStore as User);
        return (
         <Text>
             {/*
              this data (userValues) still null 
              despite userDataStore 
              is changed and has Data
             */}
          Fullname: {userValues.fullName}  
         </Text>
        );
        .
        .
        .
        export default connector(Account);
```

I know using redux state directly work for me:

```
userDataStore.fullName
     <Text>
                   {/* fullName: {userValues.fullName} */} ---> not work always null
                   fullName: {userDataStore.fullName} ---> this work good

              </Text>
    );
```

But me i want to use useState.
Any help please ?

I will be very appreciated .

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what is the reason you don't want to use the reduxState and use the `useState` hook, but you could achieve synchronisation between reduxState and the user values by adding a `useEffect` hook:

```
    const [userValues, setUserValues] = useState<User>(userDataStore as User);
    useEffect(() => {
      setUserValues(userDataStore as User)
    }, [userDataStore]);
    ...
```

This will set the `userValues` whenever the `userDataStore` changes.